# Why Vue.js @input event isn't fired when button is clicked?

Tags: vue.js

Why Vue.js @input event isn't fired when button is clicked?

When I change `count` value directly (click on input element and type new value) `alert` method is fired.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: 0

  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.count += 1;
    },
    alert: function() {
      alert('Count has been changed!');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model.number="count" @input="alert">
  <button @click="add">+1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your alert is on the input tag, not the button tag. Why would you expect clicking the button to trigger an alert?

Comment: Because change value itself should trigger event.

Comment: Change `@input` to `@change="alert('test')"`

Comment: @Miloslav21 `@input` will trigger when the user inputs something, not when the value in that box changes. You'll want to use something like `watch` if you want to watch for the count to change.

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's a bug in your code where if you delete what's in the textbox and press the "+1" button again, it just starts appending "1"s rather than increasing the count again. This also happens if you put a letter at the start of whatever's in the input box. I think the javascript is just treating the value as a String when this happens; you will probably want to handle this.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley You're right. Thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `alert` method from inside `add` method:

```js
add: function() {
  this.count += 1;
  // invoke alert()
  this.alert();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why isn't fired by input event?
```The input event fires when the value of an <input>, <select>, or <textarea> element has been changed. ```  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: yes, the event will be fired if you change the value by typing in the input field, since the browser fire the event actually. Here, the value is changing by Vue.js or JS.

Comment: @Miloslav21 you're not _really_ changing the input value, you're changing a data value that is kind of bound to the input. `@input` is specifically for a user directly modifying the field, not for any changes made to the field as a result of something like `data` changing.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley You're right. Value property isn't propably really changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its @change not @input:

`<input type="text" v-model.number="count" @change="alert">`

Alternatively:

```
watch : {

   number: function (newVal) {

     alert();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@input` isn't for any changes to an `input` tag; it's specifically triggered when a user directly modifies the `input` tag. You want something like `watch`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: 0
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.count += 1
    }
  },
  watch: {
    count: function() {
      alert('Count has been changed!')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model.number="count" />
  <button @click="add">+1</button>
</div>
```